# data received on server from android app always null

Tags: java, android

I am trying to connect from a android emulator to a application on my desktop and send a line of text.
My app is able to connect to the server, but when ever i try to read data its always null

Server application running on my desktop:

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(9001);
Socket cs = ss.accept();
if (cs.isConnected()) {
    System.out.println("Client connected.");
}

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cs.getInputStream()));

String str = reader.readLine();
System.out.println("Data:" + str);
```

Client application running in android app emulator:

```
    InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("10.0.2.2");
    Socket socket = new Socket(addr, 9001);

    if (socket.isConnected()) {
        Log.d("APP", "socket connected");
    }

    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
    String str = "this is a sample";
    pw.write(str);
```

I can see that the isConnected function of the socket on both the client and server turns true.
But the Data printed on the server is always null.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a flush call after the 'pw.write(str)' statement:

```
pw.flush();
```